# Removing elements from List containing null using Iterator

Tags: java, collections, null, iterator

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(12);
list.add(null);
list.add(22);
list.add(32);

System.out.println(list);

Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Integer a = iterator.next();
        System.out.print(a+" ");

        if(a.equals(32)){  
        iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

O/p

```
[12, null, 22, 32]
12 null Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javed.collection.Collecting.main(Collecting.java:57)
```

Trying to remove any element from List containing null gives me NullPointerException .
But can easily remove element from List containing without null.
Am I doing wrong thing by comparing integers with null ?.

If we can't remove element from List containing null than why they have allowed us to add null in the List, what's the use of it.

Comment: Why have you decided that the problem is in the `remove` line?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a null check:

```
if(a != null && a.equals(32)) {
    iterator.remove();
}
```

You can also use [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) that does the null check for you:

```
if(Objects.equals(a, 32)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional statement from:

```
if(a.equals(32)){  
   iterator.remove();
}
```

to:

```
Integer toCheck = 32;
if(toCheck.equals(a)){  
    iterator.remove();
}
```

To avoid possible null reference

Answer (score 0):

If you call any method on a `null` variable, you get a `NullPointerException`. That means if `a` is `null` and you try and call `a.equals(32)`, it will NPE.

You can null-check the variable by simply putting:

```
if (a!=null && a==32) {
    //whatever
}
```

On the other hand, you don't have to manually iterate through a list to remove a particular element from it. There is a method to do it for you:

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(32));
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely *can* remove from a list containing a null reference - you just can't call `equals` on a null reference. The problem is here:

```
if(a.equals(32))
```

That will fail with a `NullPointerException` if `a` is `null`. There's *nothing* list-specific about that. You can get exactly the same behaviour without a list or iterator in sight:

```
Integer a = null;
if (a.equals(32)) // Bang!
    ...
```

The simplest way of fixing that is to check for nullity:

```
if (a != null && a == 32)
```

(The comparison now uses unboxing, rather than boxing 32 on every iteration - which is still cheap, but not as readable IMO.)

Or have a boxed `Integer` value to start with:

```
Integer valueToRemove = 32;
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Integer a = iterator.next();
    System.out.print(a+" ");

    if(valueToRemove.equals(a)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanx, if (a != null && a == 32) this worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
if (a != null && a == 32) {
    iterator.remove();
}
```

But it's not a really good habit because of the implicits box/debox of `a`.

The fastest way will be that :

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
Integer matcher = 32;
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Integer a = iterator.next();
    System.out.print(a+" ");

    if(matcher.equals(a)){  
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will remove all your nulls from the list

```
    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```